# How do I make discord.py wait

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How can I make discord.py send a message, wait a little bit, and then send another message?

Right now, this is my command:

```
@b.command()
async def message(ctx)
  await ctx.send("First message")
  await ctx.send("Second message after 5 seconds")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `await asyncio.sleep(seconds)`. Also, your code has a few typo errors.

You should add `@` at the beginning of `b.command()` and also after `async def message(ctx)`, you need to add `:`.

```py
import asyncio
@b.command()
async def message(ctx):
    await ctx.send('First message')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await ctx.send('Second message after 5 seconds')
```

Comment: Yeah sorry about the syntax errors I usually have Visual Studio Code take care of that. Thanks so much for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To add to this post, since it is one of the first ones to pop up on google search.

`time.sleep()` **SHOULD NOT** be used. This is a blocking command and will cause  your entire bot script to halt.

Not sure where else I saw time.sleep mentioned, but this causes heartbeat issues (obviously)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35365464)

Answer (score -3):

You can also use `import time` heres an example:

```
import time

@bot.command()
async def Hello(ctx):
 time.sleep(5)
 await ctx.send("Hello1")
 time.sleep(5)
 await ctx.send("Hello2")
```